# Checking the value of a RadioButtonList using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Javascript function which takes different actions based on the value selected in a RadioButtonList:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtLocation" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                    RepeatLayout="Table" onclick="javascript:Setup()">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="First" Text="First" Value="First"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Second" Value="Second"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

My javascript function:

```
function Setup()
    {
        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("<%=rbtLocation.ClientID%>");

        for (var x = 0; x < radioButtons.length; x++)
        {
            if (radioButtons[x].checked)
            {
                alert("You checked " + radioButtons[x].id + " which has the value " + radioButtons[x].value);
                if (value == "First")
                {
                    alert("Do this");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Do that");
                }

            }
        } 
    }
```

BUT the contents of the if statement if (radioButtons[x].checked) is never executed. I've checked a few sources and cannot see the error in my code.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Does it even fire `Setup`? If yes, then what is the length of `radioButtons` after querying?

Comment: Now, this is one of the most confusing problems you could be faced with. The problem is the fact that you're fetching the name of the element; it's returning an array of radiobuttons.

Anyway, back to your problem, try to do a `console.log` of the array, and if you get an output similar to the dump of an array, then there is some faulty logic. Can you show us what the console says?

Comment: Yes Setup is entered, but length of radioButtons is only 1

Comment: Is that a valid selector for your radio buttons? You should not aim to the radio buttons before compilation, `document.getElementsByName` takes an `string` as argument referring the *name attribute* in an actual HTML `<input>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your javascript function according to this.

function Setup() {

```
        var radioButtons =  $('#<%=rbtLocation.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val()
        alert(radioButtons);            
        if (radioButtons == "First") {
                        alert("Do this");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Do that");
                    }
    }
```

Comment: That does it! I kiss you.